# How can I pass a vector as a function's argument in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function, vector

I have a function that generates test data,

```
function [A B] = generate_test_data()

    A = linspace(0.1, 15, 400)';
    eps = (0.2*rand(400,1)) - 0.1;
    B = sin(A) ./ A - eps;

end
```

I have another function that writes a 2-col matrix into a text file,

```
function write_to_file(file_name, A, B)
    fid = fopen(file_name,'w');
    fprintf(fid, '%f\t%f \n', [A B]');
    fclose(fid);
end
```

Now, I want to use those function as follows,

```
write_to_file('test_data.txt', generate_test_data());
```

But, it is generating the following error,

> `??? Input argument "B" is undefined.`
>
> `Error in ==> write_to_file at 7`
>       `fprintf(fid, '%f\t%f \n', [A B]');`

**what modifications can I make?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `write_to_file` to take three arguments, but you are calling it with two.

You can initialize A and B beforehand and then pass it to the function as follows:

```
[A B] = generate_test_data();
write_to_file('test_data.txt', A, B);
```

(Maybe there is a one-liner alternative to this.)

You can also set the function to take the second argument as a cell, which has members `A` and `B`, in this case you can define your functions as follows:

```
function [C] = generate_test_data()
    A = linspace(0.1, 15, 400)';
    eps = (0.2*rand(400,1)) - 0.1;
    B = sin(A) ./ A - eps;
    C = {A B};
end
```

and

```
function write_to_file(file_name, C)
    A = C{1}; B = C{2};
    fid = fopen(file_name,'w');
    fprintf(fid, '%f\t%f \n', [A B]');
    fclose(fid);
end
```

then you call the function as you do now, i.e. `write_to_file('test_data.txt', generate_test_data());` should work in this case.

Comment: How about this,  `function write_to_file(file_name, v)
    fid = fopen(file_name,'w');
    fprintf(fid, '%f\t%f \n', v');
    fclose(fid);
end`

`write_to_file('test_data.txt', generate_test_data());`

Comment: If `generate_test_data()` is generating `v` as you want, yes, why not :)

Comment: Does this have any drawback?

Comment: I don't think so. Depending on the size of `A` and `B` using a cell, or a struct, or using those two as separate variables might be different in terms of performance. But if the matrices are small enough, it should not be important.

Comment: Yes, that should be small enough :)